# TFS History Lost

Tags: branch

I have come across an issue that looks like TFS has permanently deleted a branch and all of its history and is not giving me the ability to interact with any of the changesets that were in that branch.  Here is what happened:

1. I created a new branch(A) off of an existing branch(B).
2. I used A for a few months.
3. I merged everything in A back to B.
4. I deleted A by right clicking on the branch in Source Control Explorer and clicking delete and checked in the change.
5. [At this point I didn't check to see if A could be undeleted, and didn't notice anything amiss]
6. 2 weeks pass
7. Now I want to view the history of a file that was merged
8. I go to the visual studio settings and check the box that shows all deleted items
9. A is nowhere to be found
10. I check to see if some other branches that I had deleted in the past were visible, and they are still present.
11. I look in the change history of the parent directory and I can't even see the changeset from when I deleted A.

    - I have admin access to the TFS database, but don't understand the schema well enough to search for all "delete" changesets.
    - I've tried to use the API in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client to get more information, but it isn't providing any more records that the TFS history window did

**Update**

I just ran a a tf destroy command on a test branch to see what the symptoms are, and the symptoms are consistent with what I'm experiencing.  I suspect that this branch was destroyed, now my goal is to find out if destroy leaves behind any information about who or when

Comment: Can you see the Delete Changeset in "B"?

Comment: I cannot, though I wouldn't expect to see it it B.  I can see the merge changeset in B, but not the delete.

Comment: What about doing a "View History" at project level ($/MyProject) ?

Comment: That shows all changesets for all other branches, all changesets for A are simply absent, including the initial branch, all changes and the delete.

Comment: Is it possible some "destroyed" it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2341284/383710

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  I've added an update to my original post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7437/discussion-between-vic-peters-and-daveshaw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation reveals that a team member on a different project had run a cleanup script during the two week period that had invoked the destroy command, accidentally destroying some of our deleted branches.  The advice in [How to find out who ran the TFS Destroy Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185018/how-to-find-out-who-ran-the-tfs-destroy-command/9185435#comment11572740_9185435) revealed who it was, and how it had happened.