# How to find out who ran the TFS Destroy Command?

Tags: tfs, audit, destroy

I have reason to believe that the TFS Destroy command was run on my server.  Does TFS provide a way to find out who and when it was done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TFS logs all user-initiated commands in the database for 14 days.

Try connect to your `Tfs_Collection` database and run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Command WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Command = 'Destroy'
```

Additionally, any time a `Destroy` command is run, an event is logged to the `Application` Event Log on the Application Tier that processed the command.

Comment: Martin Woodward's not lying when he says there's nothing you don't know :D

Comment: Excellent answer, I thought there would be a way to get this from the database. It's a shame it's not recorded in the source control history though.

Comment: This gave me exactly the information I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to your earlier question. I don't think TFS provides an easy way (or any way) to do this. You can however narrow down the list of suspects, only users in the "project administrator" or "project collection administrator" groups have permissions to do a destroy. Contributors will get an error message if they run tf destroy. It does seem a bit of an oversight that this action isn't audited so hopefully someone will add an answer that allows you to get to the bottom of this.